# Zusammenschreiben von Wörtern

Tags: compound, writing

Schreibt man die Wörter, die aus zwei Wörtern bestehen, zusammen oder getrennt oder mit einem Strich?

z.B.

- die Sport Aktivität
- die Sportaktivität
- die Sport-Aktivität

Generell, wann schreiben wir zwei Wörter zusammen, wann getrennt und wann mit einem Strich?